# How to capture the most exterior element when click event occurs

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener, event-bubbling, event-capturing

I need to get the most element when clicking in a div... Such as this...

```
 <div id="show_trash_id" class="switch switch-xs">
   <input type="checkbox"/>
   <span class="slider round">
     <span class="text-on">ON</span>
     <span class="text-off">OFF</span>
   </span>
 </div>
```

I think that this is related to some sort of bubbling or capturing effect., however I cannot handle that... I have already tried to do `event.stopPropagation()` or using `useCature` both unsuccessfully.

```
function capture (event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   console.log(event.target);
}
document.querySelector('#show_trash_id').addEventListener('click', capture, true)
```

In short what I want is to get the following bellow displayed in the console:

```
     <div id="show_trash_id" class="switch switch-xs">
       <input type="checkbox"/>
       <span class="slider round">
         <span class="text-on">ON</span>
         <span class="text-off">OFF</span>
       </span>
     </div>
```

Comment: You could use `console.log(event.currentTarget)`

Comment: That's exactly what  need... Thank you, @AlphaHowl

Comment: Oh, I was starting to write an answer using built in `event` methods, but if you don't need it, i guess ill stop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem before. My solution has always been to use an anonymous function and use the `this` keyword instead of `event.target`, as it refers to the element the event listener was added to.

Note however that the anonymous function cannot be an arrow function, as `this` in the context of an arrow function is the window.

```js
document.querySelector('#show_trash_id').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
 <div id="show_trash_id" class="switch switch-xs">
   <input type="checkbox"/>
   <span class="slider round">
     <span class="text-on">ON</span>
     <span class="text-off">OFF</span>
   </span>
 </div>
```